# EF - set Identity not a primary key and then use as a foreign key in another table

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Is it possible to build a relationship like below?

Or what is the best way to make this?

I have a parent table `SnapShotPriceList` with a composite key (built from foreign keys) and they provide a unique record in this table.

I would like the create child table `SnapPriceListProcess` and make relationship to parent table not by using this complex key but by using some unique column. Does this make sense? Can I do something like that? By adding `SnapPricelistId` ?
Many thanks for any tips.

```
[Table("SnapShotPriceList")]
public class SnapShotPriceList
{
    // auton increment but not primary key
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SnapPriceListId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("ProjectId", Order = 0)]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("PriceListId", Order = 1)]
    public int PriceListId { get; set; }

    public int CrtUsrnm { get; set; }
    public DateTime CrtTmstmp { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PriceListId")]
    public virtual PriceList PriceList { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PriceListId, ProjectId")]
    public virtual ProjectPriceList ProjectPriceList { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SnapShotPriceListProcess> SnapShotPriceListProcesses { get; set; }
}

[Table("SnapPriceListProcess")]
public class SnapShotPriceListProcess
{
    [Key, Column("SnapProcessId", Order = 0)]
    public int SnapProcessId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SnapPriceListId")]
    public virtual SnapShotPriceList SnapShotPriceList{ get; set; }

    // some other fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EF6 does not support Foreign Keys that reference Alternate Keys.  EF Core does (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys) but has other limitations.

But it's usually a bad idea to introduce a new key for this.  The compound key will typically be more efficient, as "child" rows will be stored together.